# In Apache, is there a way to limit the number of new connections per second/hour/day?

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, connection

To clarify, I do not wish to limit the number of simultaneous connections, nor do I want to limit the number of HTTP requests. I only want to limit the number of NEW connections per IP.

I want to do this because most web crawlers do not have keep-alive functionality and thus they open a new connection for every request.

I vaguely remember reading about a mod that could do this, but I can't remember the name. Hopefully, someone here can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do it in apache..  I'd do it at network layer with iptables.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 86400 --hitcount 100 -j REJECT
```

Change 86400 to the number of seconds you want to keep the block for (86400 is 1 day), and 100, is the hit count, how many you're prepared to allow per IP.

You can also change `-j REJECT` to `-j DROP`, which defines the packet behaviour when the condition is met. `DROP` seamlessly drops packets, and `REJECT` returns a "port unreachable" or similar error.

That said, there was a `mod_throttle` that would do something similar, but I can't seem to find much information about it. I think it feels neater to do this kind of thing at the network/kernel level, rather than in Apache. Apache is good at serving requests.  Let it do what it does best, and don't burden it with having to track connections too.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to serve a message to the user's who get blocked, just in case there are any false positives. Any idea how I could do that? I suppose I could run a cron job that checks the output of iptables every few minutes, and places the blacklisted IPs into a .htaccess file or something similar.

Comment: A htaccess file probably wouldn't work, because the traffic would never actually hit the server.  The best idea would be to rewrite the packet and redirect it.

Answer (score 2):

you could tune the iptables rule so that requests beyond the limit are redirected to another port (e.g. TCP 8080) where another instance of Apache serves a static page with your message to users

Comment: Neat idea, I like it!

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea. Maybe something a little more lightweight than Apache, though. Thanks

Comment: Nginx or Lighttpd perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [mod_qos](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that mod only allows you to limit the number of concurrent connections per IP, which isn't what I want to do.

Comment: I could be wrong ;)